# Place FFMPEG videos side by side, allign by frame number

Tags: video, ffmpeg

So, I have 2 videos I would like to place side by side. I would like to align them by a frame number that I know for each video, assuming both videos have the same FPS. The frame numbers were found using the following command.

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" "output/%08d.jpg"
```

So, let's say I know the frame number I want to align for Video A is 126, while for Video B the frame number is 179. I want to align the videos side by side with these two frames lining up, so that the resulting video would be displaying Video A frame 126 at the same time as Video B frame 179. The resulting video also shouldn't have any pieces from either video removed, so if one of the videos hasn't started or isn't finished, the resulting video keeps playing the active video, rather than having only the times when both videos are supposed to be playing. I also want to align both audio tracks as well.

For this question I would prefer a single-command solution where I only need to input the videos and frame numbers I want to align, rather than having to do several steps manually.

Comment: Are both videos constant-frame rate?

Comment: @Mulvya Yes, they both have the same frame rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -i b.mp4
 -filter_complex
   "[1]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+d/FRAME_RATE/TB[b];
    [0][b]hstack[v];
    [1]adelay=dt|dt[ba];
    [0][ba]amix[a]"
 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" out.mp4
```

`d` has to be replaced by the difference in frame alignment and is applied to the video which will start later. In your Q, #126 of A is to be aligned with #179 of B, so A gets delayed by 53 frames, so `d=53`. My command applies the video and audio delay to the 2nd input, so either feed them in that order, or switch the `[1]` with `[0]` in `setpts` and `adelay` and `[0]` with `[1]` in hstack and amix.

Since audio frame rates are different, you will have to supply a time value `dt` in milliseconds. A 53 frame video delay for a video that's 25 fps corresponds to an audio delay of `53/25 = 2.12 (s) = 2120 (ms)`

Due to how `hstack` works. The first frame of the delayed video will appear frozen till it is time for it to start playing. Same for the last frame of the video that finishes first. The hstack filter also requires that the height dimension of the two videos be the same.

Comment: Ok, what would I do if video A started first, so the difference in frames would be negative?

Comment: I cover that in the first para.

Comment: Ok, I get this error:
[Parsed_adelay_2 @ 0x77b8c0] At least one delay >0 must be specified.
[Parsed_adelay_2 @ 0x77b8c0] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_adelay_2
Error configuring complex filters.
Invalid argument


Also, are there supposed to be backslashes in the command? I'm running it on Bash.

Comment: adelay part should look like this: `[1]adelay=2120|2120[ba];`. I work on Windows, so don't know what escaping, if any, bash requires.

Comment: Okay, I noticed one error. If I switch the 0 and 1 like you said for the delay, it switches the sides when the video is placed side by side. I want video A on the left and Video B on the right.

Comment: You can swap the order of inputs to the hstack, so `[b][0]hstack..` The `b` refers to the processed input, and `0` to the first input.